# What is the best way to store static data from API with AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I wonder what is the best practice for storing lists from different API's and display them without the need to make redundant API requests.

Suppose user logged in - i want to store all the pages static lists for dropdown menus in a way that they will be available to all the controllers - by doing the API requests once.

The options that i came across are the following:

1. creating a factory and store the data in $rootScope.
2. Use sessionStorage.

What is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider storing data in rootscope a very bad practice.

I'd suggest using this package
https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache

You have nicely explained inside documentation why would you use this package instead of angulars built in $cacheFactory service.

Comment: Perhaps do you have an example of how to cache API data ? i read the documentation but unfortunately couldn't figure it out